# VirtualBox window does not appear

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-11

Yesterday, I created a new virtual machine with Virtualbox 7 installed on Windows 11 (it was working then).

However, when I started it today, the Virtualbox virtual machine list window did not appear.

As far as Task Manager is concerned, the process itself seems to be running:
[image: Task manager]

There was a Windows update this morning, but I don't know if that is related to this problem.

I have tried rebooting, reinstalling VirtualBox, installing with winget and "Repair" in the Virtualbox installer, but the problem persists.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to start Virtualbox many times since then, and for some reason it started successfully once, and has started successfully since then.